# Some derivation in mechanics

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

I have the following derivation in my physics book I don't know how did they derive them

$\frac{d}{dt} \Sigma{_i}[(\vec{r}_{cm} + \vec{r_i})\times m_i(\vec{v}_{cm} + \vec{v_i})]$ = $\Sigma{_i}[\vec{v}_{cm} \times m_i \vec{v}_{cm} + \vec{r}_{cm} \times m_i \vec{a}_{cm} + \vec{v}_{cm}\times m_i\vec{v_i} + \vec{r}_{cm}\times m_i\vec{a_i} + \vec{v_i}\times m_i\vec{v}_{cm} + \vec{r_i}\times m_i\vec{a}_{cm} + \vec{v_i}\times m_i\vec{v_i} + \vec{r}\times m_i\vec{a_i}]$

I don't know how they expanded this cross product I understand how they derived the rest that is how they got $\tau= \vec{r}_{cm}\times \vec{a}_{cm} + \Sigma(\vec{r_i} \times F_i)$ which makes intuitive sense but I don't understand how they expanded that cross product in that particular manner if someone could shed some light on that it would be perfect.

Comment: Expand the top expression into four terms $thing_1 \times thing_2$. Then take the time derivative of each, with $(d/dt)(thing_1 \times thing_2) = (d/dt)thing_1 \times thing_2 + thing_1 \times (d/dt)thing_2$. Finally, realize that $(d/dt)\vec{r} = \vec{v}$. and $ (d/dt)\vec{ v} = \vec{a}$. With that, you should find all 8 terms of the second expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross product is distributive over addition. $$(r_{cm} + r_i)\wedge (v_{cm} + v_{i}) = r_{cm}\wedge v_{cm} + r_{cm} \wedge v_{i} + r_{i}\wedge v_{cm} + r_i \wedge v_i $$ All these terms are time dependant so when you introduce the differential you must apply the product rule. So we get $$\dot{r}_{cm}\wedge v_{cm} +r_{cm}\wedge \dot{v}_{cm}  + \dot{r}_{cm} \wedge v_{i} + r_{cm} \wedge \dot{v}_{i} + \dot{r}_{i}\wedge v_{cm} + r_{i}\wedge \dot{v}_{cm} + \dot{r}_i \wedge v_i +r_i \wedge \dot{v}_i $$ Mass is constant with time so you can just pull it out the derivate and cross product. The dots denote time derivatives so $\dot{r}_{cm} =v_{cm}$ etc.

Comment: It's funny that you write "cross product" and then render the wedge product: $\wedge$.  Also, to get $\dot {r}_{cm}$, type `$\dot {r}_{cm}$` -- because $\dot {r_{cm}}$ looks awfully weird.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the tip on the dot, will fix it now. Wedge product and cross product have little difference, I'm just used to writing with the wedge product notation.

Comment: I didn't know that cross product have the properties of that when you apply differential over them it behaves as multiplication. Alright that makes sense thank you.

Comment: I see. They do act like that. Handy trick